# rename files by omitting numbers form files names error

Tags: python-2.7

I try to follow an example in an online course to create a function to change the files name by omitting the numbers from the files name. But I got this error:

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

But the code runs fine on the video that I watched

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # (1) get file naems from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\prank")
    #print (file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print (" Currnet Wroking Directory is " +saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\prank")


    # (2) for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
        os.chdir (saved_path)



rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one out, there is no need to change the working directory, its not a good practice. Also if you are renaming files in C: you may have to execute the code as administrator.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # directoy with the files
    directory=r"C:\prank"
    # (1) get file names from a folder 
    file_list = os.listdir(directory) # this is the folder with the files
    # (2) for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list:
        new_name=''.join([s for s in file_name if s not in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']]) # remove numbers 
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory,file_name),os.path.join(directory,new_name))

rename_files()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine , now I understand how the code works